# How to write a variable in the array

Tags: php, arrays, xlsx

I try to write a string into a variable in between an array

```
if ($row_klasse['RabKlNummerVK'] != ''){
    $headerrabklasse = '\'Rabatt\'\=\>\'price\'\,';
}
else {$headerrabklasse = '';}
```

then I want to write the variable $headerrabklasse in:

```
$writer = new XLSXWriter();

$writer->writeSheetHeader (Preisliste, array(
        'Marke'=>'string',
        'Range'=>'string',
        'Artikelnummer'=>'string',
        'Bezeichnung'=>'string', 
        'EAN'=>'string', 
        'kg netto'=>'zahl3', 
        'VE'=>'string', 
        'Steuer'=>'string', 
        'Listenpreis'=>'euro',
        $headerrabklasse
        'Nettopreis'=>'price3',
        'UVP'=>'price'),
        ['auto_filter'=>true, 'widths'=>[20,50,15,45,15,8,8,8,8,8], 
        'font-style'=>'bold', 'fill'=>'#eee', 
        'freeze_rows'=>1, 
        'freeze_columns'=>0] );
```

And I always get an error...
HAs anybody an idea?

Comment: Please mention the language. I assume it is python, because of xlsxwriter.

Comment: @Vishnudev it is php

Comment: See, It always creates confusion if you don't mention language.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can easily append data to array like this:

```
//Define array with default values
//BTW: if you work with PHP >= 5.4 better to use [] instead of array()
$sheetHeaders = array(
    'Marke'=>'string',
    'Range'=>'string',
    'Artikelnummer'=>'string',
    'Bezeichnung'=>'string',
    'EAN'=>'string',
    'kg netto'=>'zahl3',
    'VE'=>'string',
    'Steuer'=>'string',
    'Listenpreis'=>'euro',
    'Nettopreis'=>'price3',
    'UVP'=>'price'
);

if ($row_klasse['RabKlNummerVK'] != ''){
    //Here you append data to existing array in format: array[key] = value
    $sheetHeaders['Rabatt'] = 'price';
}

//Then use fulfilled array as you want
$writer->writeSheetHeader ($preisliste, $sheetHeaders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array takes keys and values, so you need to write a key name, and pass the variable as a value. I also noticed you were mixing Array declarations. In PHP you can call an array like this:

```
Array(el1, el2, ...)
```

or like this:

```
[el1, el1, ...]
```

Either one is fine, but for best practices you want to pick one and stick with it.

```
$writer->writeSheetHeader(Preisliste, [
        'Marke'=>'string',
        ...
        'MyNewKeyName' => $headerrabklasse,
        ...
    ],
    [
       ...
    ] 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wan't to do this one:

```
if ($row_klasse['RabKlNummerVK'] != '') {
    $headerrabklasse = ['Rabatt' => 'price'];
}
else {$headerrabklasse = [];}
```

You could do stuff like that:

```
$writer->writeSheetHeader (Preisliste, array_merge(array(
    'Marke'=>'string',
    'Range'=>'string',
    'Artikelnummer'=>'string',
    'Bezeichnung'=>'string', 
    'EAN'=>'string', 
    'kg netto'=>'zahl3', 
    'VE'=>'string', 
    'Steuer'=>'string', 
    'Listenpreis'=>'euro',
    'Nettopreis'=>'price3',
    'UVP'=>'price'),
    ['auto_filter'=>true, 'widths'=>[20,50,15,45,15,8,8,8,8,8], 
    'font-style'=>'bold', 'fill'=>'#eee', 
    'freeze_rows'=>1, 
    'freeze_columns'=>0]), $headerrabklasse);
```